# Expectation value of vectors for an electron in ground state of H atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Why can't I make the following statement: 
<$\vec{r}$>=$<r\hat{r}$>= $<r>\hat{r}$

I know this is not true since <$\vec{r}$>=0 and $<r>= \frac{3}{2}$$a_{0}$

How about the validity of this statement ?: 
<$\vec{x}$>=$<x>\hat{x}$

Comment: What is the $\hat{r}$ on the r.h.s. of your first statement supposed to be?

Comment: To expand on @ACuriousMind's comment, the unit vectors in Cartesean coordinates are strictly constant, but the radial unit vector in spherical coordinates is a function of the angular coordinates $\hat{r} = \hat{r}(\theta,\phi)$. Now, as an exercise for the student, treat the average as a sum (or integral) and explain why $\hat{r}$ can not be pulled out of the sum in the same way that $\hat{x}$ can be.

Answer (score 0):

$r$ is a positive only quantity as it is the magnitude of a vector.  Thus, its average value cannot be $0$ unless the probability density in 3d space is negative somewhere, which does not happen in traditional quantum mechanics.

One problem with your expression is you forgot that the various vectors $\hat r$ aren't in general in the same direction: you can't take $\hat r$ outside the average value - it's not a constant vector during the integration as it direction changes depending where you are in space.  In other words, $\langle \vec r\rangle \ne \langle r\rangle \hat r$.

The problem of the changing direction of $\hat r$ is tied to the choice of coordinate system: in spherical coordinates, the direction of the basis vectors $\hat r,\hat \theta,\hat \phi$ is not constant and as a result it is very very awkward to add in spherical; and adding is what you do when you take an average - think of taking the average of a discrete rather than continuous distribution, so the $\int$ is a $\sum$.

The convenient coordinate system to easily add vectors is the Cartesian system.  Thus start with $\vec r=\hat x x+\hat y y+\hat z z$ and consider $$
\langle \vec r\rangle = \langle x\rangle \hat x + \langle y\rangle \hat y+\langle z\rangle \hat z \, . 
$$
The basis vectors are fixed in orientation throughout the integration needed to find the average value, so you can take these out of the averaging process.

Finally note that the coordinate $x$ can be positive and negative value, so you can have $\langle x\rangle=0$; ditto for $y$ and $z$.  This will
produce, for the ground state of hydrogen, $\langle \vec r\rangle=0$, meaning on average the electron is centered with the atom, but on average the *distance* of the electron to the nucleus will be non-zero.

Combining these two results, you find that the average position of the electron is on a sphere of radius $\langle r\rangle$ but in no particular point on the sphere, i.e. in no specific $\hat r$ direction.

You can make an analogy with vectors from the origin to a circle.  The average $\vec r$ is clearly $0$ since every *direction* of this vector is equiprobable.  Yet the average *distance* between a point and the origin is certainly not $0$.  In the first case, you are taking 
$\langle \vec r\rangle=\hat x\langle x\rangle +\hat y\langle y\rangle$ while in the second you are taking $\langle r\rangle$.

If you think vectors on a circle are too restrictive because $r$ is fixed, think of vectors somewhere on an annulus of inner radius $r_1$ and outer radius $r_2$.  Presumably then $\langle r\rangle=(r_1+r_2)/2\ne 0$ but
$\langle \vec r\rangle=0$ still.

Comment: Thank you.  How could I go about finding the expectation for the momentum vector? I've been told that it is zero  and this make sense since  a nonzero expectation value for the momentum  vector would mean I'd seen an  electron that's escaping from the nucleus.

Comment: Since $p_x\sim d/dx$ draw your conclusions for $\langle \vec p\rangle$.  For $\langle p\rangle$ you *need* to take the Fourier transform.