# The most probable value for x for an electron in the ground state in H atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

To find the most probable radius of an electron in the  ground state of a H atom you simply take the derivative of the probability distribution to find the value of r such that p(r)=max; this occurs when r=$a_0$ (the Bohr radius). Now I want to find the most probable value for x for an electron in the ground state in H atom.  Do I simply rewrite $p(r)=\frac{1}{\pi a^3}e^{-r/a}$ in terms of Cartesian coordinates via $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$  and take the partial derivative with respect with x to find its maximum value? Or maybe I can simply make an argument that 3D wavefunction is symmetric about the origin, so most like value of x is at the center? Thanks.

Comment: I think you'd need to integrate your probability density function (i.e., the square of the wave function) in $y$ and $z$ to the whole range, so that you are left with the distribution only for $x$, and then take the derivative.

Comment: @anonymous that does make sense. Do you know what would be the limits (range) of the integrals for z and y?

Comment: Jerry, if you know how to take $\langle r \rangle$ then you can deduce the limits on the Cartesean coordinates from that. Right? You've asked three questions on this subject in the last twenty-four hours and to me it feels like you are treating each one as a separate recipe when you need to be treating them as variations on a theme that are all understood using the same tools. So ask yourself, *"In what part(s) of space is my wave-function defined?"* and go from there.

Comment: @dmckee You are probably talking about Kane Billiot. We are in the same class. He deleted his questions, so mine would not get mark as duplicate.

Comment: No, I'm talking about your approach to this problem and compared to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/320453 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/320445. These are three facets of the same thing. Your questions (and Kane's) feel like you aren't seeing them in a single mathematical context—like you are looking for separate instructions for each one. You'll find this work easier if you master the framework so that you don't have to remember of lot of separate things.

Comment: @Jerry why doesn't it make sense? if you have a probability density function f(x,y,z) and you want the probability function for only one variable, you integrate in the other two. Also, the limits should be to the whole space, i.e. from $-\infty$ to $\infty$